# エクセルグラフの軸色の一部変更

Tags: excel

エクセルで棒グラフを作成しています。
その際横軸を（西暦/月/日）にしているのですが，土曜日と日曜日の色が変更できずに困っています。

#### 試したこと

軸の表示形式で　[赤][=1]aaa,aaaとしたのですが，曜日だけが表示され色は変わりませんでした。

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

ecxel 2013

Comment: こちらの質問はオフトピックではなく、適切な質問だと思いましたのでメタにスレッドを立てました。 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2200/excel%E5%86%85%E9%83%A8%E3%81%AE%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%82%84%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E3%81%AE%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AF%E3%82%AA%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%83%94%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/35636 マルチポスト

Answer (score 8):

縦棒のグラフで複数色の棒が使いたい場合、下記のようにできます：

1. 週末と週末じゃないデータを別の列に入れる
2. 棒グラフを積み上げ棒に設定し、その複数の列を利用する

例えば、データはこちらの場合：

[image: データ]

C列に`=MOD(WEEKDAY(A12),7)<=1`を入れたら、`TRUE/FALSE`で週末かどうかを検出します（複数の方法はありますが、週末の場合は`=WEEKDAY()`が0又は7になる場合、`=MOD(,7)`を利用することで週末が0又は1になりますので、かなり簡単です）。

そこからD列とE列に、週末・週末じゃないデータを入れます。複数の方法はありますが、D列に`=IF(C2,"",B2)`とE列に`=IF(C2,B2,"")`にすると分かれてきます。（C列の数式とD/E列の数式を組み合わせてもいいです）。

結果的にデータは下記になります：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

グラフをする時に、積み上げ棒を選んで、データをA/D/E列にします（基本的にA~Cを選んで、B/Cの枠をD/Eに移動させるのが楽です）：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

結果のグラフはデフォルトで下記のようになります：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]